# WPF WebBrowser NavigateToString vs NavigateToStream (hebrew/non-utf8 encodings)

Tags: wpf, browser, hebrew

When I use WPF WebBrowser's NavigateToString method to display UTF8 html (with hebrew text in it) it's displayed perfectly.

However, when I try to use the NavigateToString to display html with hebrew text in it in a non-utf8 encoding (CodePage 1255 to be exact) the hebrew is messed up.

I checked the cp1255 string in Visual Studio's debugger and it looks great, and also when I save the source of the web browser's contents and open it with an external browser it looks great.

If I use the NavigateToStream method instead of the NavigateToString method it works great.

What's the problem with the NavigateToString? am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

NavigateToString= NavigateToStream + UTF8NoBOM
Use NavigateToStream  and make sure you have the correct encoding in the stream data.

Comment: Your comment implies that the original poster did something wrong. But what do you think they should have done instead? You say to "make sure you have the correct encoding", but there is no way to specify an encoding - .NET's `String` type is, by definition, a sequence of UTF-16 code units. That's something you can't change even if you want to. So any API that takes a string (e.g. `NavigateToString`) is by definition asking for a sequence of UTF-16 code units. The fact that `NavigateToString` fails to pass a BOM looks like a bug, because IE will often misidentify BOMless UTF-8 as cp1255.